# How to make a projection with TypeOrm's MongoRepository

Tags: node.js, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

I'm using NestJs with TypeOrm and I need to make a projection from one of my collections: I want to query all documents but I just need 2 fields per document.

This can be done with Mongo ([docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-_id-field-only)

```
db.inventory.find( { status: "A" }, { item: 1, status: 1 } )
```

But I don't see how I can do the same thing with [MongoRepository from TypeOrm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/mongodb.md)

```
  private readonly repository: MongoRepository<Inventory>;
  ...
  this.repository.find({}, { item: 1, status: 1});
```

This doesn't work, because `find` expects 0 or 1 argument. Is something like this possible with TypeOrm or should I query all the documents and filter everything I don't need out? This could potentially cause a memory issue on my server :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you chain `.project()` on the `.find()` call?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this -

```ts
private readonly repository: MongoRepository<Inventory>;
  ...
  this.repository.find({where: { id: /* Any ID */ }, select: {item: true, status: true} });
```